# How to remove "rubbish" from column to stay only phone number in SQL?

Tags: sql, regex, hive, phone-number

I have table in sql like below:

```
PHONE_NUMBER
--------
ppa:+77845678021@abc.gbc443.gbc356.7kffooopppp.deu  
tel:+77695002395    
....
```

As you can see I have in COL1 phone numbers with a lot of "rubbish" and I need to convert values in that column to have something like below (only phone number):

```
PHONE_NUMBER
--------
77845678021 
77695002395 
....
```

How can I do that in SQL ?

Comment: With something like `regex_extract`, for example.

Comment: What BDMS is being used? And why have you dropped `+` from numbers in your column?

Comment: markalex - could you present your solution in cole based on my example, please ?

Comment: markalex - it is HiveQL, because these data are from Hadoop, and exactly I need remove +

Comment: Careful! If you haven't done so read [Falsehoods programmers believe about phone numbers](https://github.com/google/libphonenumber/blob/master/FALSEHOODS.md). Especially if your application is intended for global use.

Comment: Use replace function with regex

Comment: yeras, could you present using my example data how to use replace ?

Comment: @dingaro, go delete this quesion yourself if it is no longer needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `regexp_substr`. Something like this:

```sql
select regexp_substr(PHONE_NUMBER, '[0-9]{11,14}') PHONE_NUMBER
  from my_table
```

Demo for MySQL can be seen [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/ikR2NgI1).

This will extract first block of 11 to 14 digits. Since you haven't provided any specification on phone format, I'm guessing here.

EDIT: For Hive `regexp_extract` should be used instead:

```sql
select regexp_extract(PHONE_NUMBER, '[0-9]{11,14}') PHONE_NUMBER
  from my_table
```

Comment: markalex - I have ERROR like that using your code: KeyError: '11,14'

Comment: It's strange, because as I can see Hive doesn't even have `regexp_substr`, it has `regexp_extract` instead. @dingaro

Comment: i changed to regexp_extract and I still have ERROR: KeyError: '11,14'

Comment: @dingaro i am reading online that the regex looks very different between different versions of HiveQL, so I think that is impossible to answer at the moment. Unless people make a code for each possible version.

Comment: Johan, but do you have some example idea what can work ?

Comment: @dingaro could make some examples, but since i dont know the version it could potentially take hours instead of minutes and a lot of back and forth. I think there is better use of my time. look at the documentation on regex it changes depending on the version of hive